# Not able to decode very large data which is stored in mysql database using Base64 decoding in java

Tags: java, jsp, base64

***I want to take data from mysql database and download it.***

```
        import java.util.Base64;
```

**When I am trying below code I am not getting any output...**

```
        String content = rt.getString("data1");
        byte[] conArray = content.getBytes();
        byte[] decodeBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(conArray); 
        String decode = new String(decodeBytes, "UTF_8");
        System.out.println(decode);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filedetails[0] + "\"");
        out.write(decode);
```

**Here is my encoding part....**

```
    byte[] a = fileItem.get();
    byte[] encodedfile = Base64.getEncoder().encode(a);
    String s = new String(encodedfile, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(s);
```

**Without decoding I am getting encoded string, so no problem in code**

```
        String content = rt.getString("data1");
        System.out.println(content);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filedetails[0] + "\"");
        out.write(content);
```

**And when I try online Base64 Encoder decoder, I am getting correct output.**

**Edit:**

Data in mysql - hey there

After applying Base64 encoding and stored in mysql **data** column - aGV5IHRoZXJl

I am trying to decode this string from above code.

Getting aGV5IHRoZXJl when printing content (same which is stored in database column)

When printing decode - nothing is printed

Comment: I notice you are using "UTF-8" everywhere, except `String.getBytes()`  Try `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` see if that helps.

Comment: Your question is incomplete.  We need to see actual data, its encoded value and the results of the decode that does not work.  You will have to insert debug logging at the appropriate places to get these values.  Without that, the question cannot be answered.  To be very specific, in the "code that does not work" we need to see the values of `content` and `decode`, plus the original text that was encoded to produce `content`.

Comment: @JimGarrison - edited. Please have a look.

Comment: @markspace- tried but still same problem.

Comment: The original data you're encoding appears to be bytes, not text (`byte[] a = fileItem.get();`. Why are you then assuming it was originally UTF-8-encoded text?

Comment: I am getting data from file. @JonSkeet

Comment: That doesn't answer why you're then assuming it's a string afterwards: `String decode = new String(decodeBytes, "UTF_8");` You started with a `byte[]` from the file, so your decoding process should end with a `byte[]` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   byte[] decodeBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(conArray); 
    //String decode = new String(decodeBytes, "UTF_8");
    System.out.println(decode);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filedetails[0] + "\"");
    out.write(decodeBytes);
```

The bytes must be written as-is, with an OutputStream, not as text with a Writer.
Those bytes probably are not a valid UTF-8 sequence anyways, and converting bytes to chars (twice the memory) is a bit too much anyway.

Maybe you need to alter out:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
```